# Animate PopupMenuItem in dojo

Tags: dojo

I want to apply animation to dojo PopupMenuItem

here is code [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agha_ali22/ntkhy9q3/)

Below is how i am creating popup

```
var pSubMenu2 = new Menu();
  pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCopy",
    style: "display:inline-block"
  }));
  pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",
    style: "display:inline-block"

  }));
  pMenu.addChild(new PopupMenuItem({
    iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconPaste",
    popup: pSubMenu2
  }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 animation property.

Live example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ntkhy9q3/13/

With right to left animation:

https://jsfiddle.net/ntkhy9q3/19/

You can learn more about animation in CSS3 here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation

Alternative you can use JS animation, using `dojo/fx`, you can learn more about it at the following link:

https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/fx.html

In your specific case I would suggest you using CSS3 approach.

```
.dijitMenuItemIconCell {
  height: 40px !important;
  width: 40px !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Firefox < 16 */

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Internet Explorer */

@-ms-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/* Opera < 12.1 */

@-o-keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: actually i want submenu to slide from right to left with animation.

Comment: @Haider I have edit my answer adding a quick example of how to add an animation right to left, link here: https://jsfiddle.net/ntkhy9q3/19/  off-course you can adjust the style as for your use case. I hope you find my answer useful, in that case, please do not forget to accept or up-vote my answer :) thanks